# closesocket triggers WSARecvFrom completion routine

Tags: winsock

I noticed that when I call closesocket, the completion routine of WSARecvFrom (which by that time waits for incoming data) is being triggered with dwError=0 and cbTransferred=garbage, eve though there is no incoming data pending for that socket.

Any way for it not to be called when i close the socket? I tried to call shutdown prior to closesocket, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

What value does WSARecvFrom() itself return?  I have not used WSARecvFrom() myself, but MSDN says dwError is a completion status, so I would imagine that 0 means an actual error, or no data.

Also, are you calling CancelIo() before calling closesocket()?

Comment: Calling CancelIO is very bad.